# How to set background color for JVector Map?

Tags: javascript, background-color, jvectormap

I have the following code to initialize JVector map:

```
      map = new jvm.WorldMap({
          map: 'us_aea_en',
          // backgroundColor:  #FFFFFF, //Only this line does not work.
          container: $('#map'),
          series: {
            regions: [{
              attribute: 'fill'
            }]
          }
        });
```

The above line: `backgroundColor:  #FFFFFF` does not execute. I read the API documentation, it seems to have correct syntax. The code works perfect except for that line. How to set the background? Are there any other ways to set the background color?

Comment: Did you try to enclose `#FFFFFF` in quotes, like `'#FFFFFF'`? :)

Comment: @Denis Malinovsky thanks you that works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Denis Malinovsky, I finally figured out that
The answer is:
`backgroundColor:  "#FFFFFF"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `backgroundColor` to be empty, e.g. "", and then specify the background color in css by specifying it in the `.jvectormap-container` class:

Javascript:

```
var mapObject = $(map).vectorMap({
    map: 'us_aea',
    backgroundColor: ""
});
```

Css:

```
.jvectormap-container {
    background-color: navy;
}
```